# Reload recaptcha on browser back button

Tags: jquery, reload, recaptcha, back

I have tried numerous methods to reload the image when paging back but no matter what i try i get the same image.  Some methods were close ( i can see the image refresh, but the recaptcha server responds back and the previous image reappears).  Is there some trick to getting the image to reload when clicking the back button?  I dont want my users to have to re-enter all the form information if they type the security words incorrectly.  I also want to avoid storing all the information.  The page is classic asp, so jquery or ajax methods would be the route to go, or so id assume.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a quick hack that fixes this issue. On the page with the recaptcha add the following jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form_div").Show();
);
</script>
```

Just replace "#form_div" with whatever div houses your form. Now when the user hits the back button it refreshes the recaptcha image.  It is a hack in every sense of the word, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Call your refresh method from `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){ /* refresh here */ }
```

Comment: Test this: `window.onload = function(){ alert(1); }`. You should see the alert when paging back.

Comment: i do get the alert window when paging back, however their server response is later, so when i use the reload method their server overrides my method

Comment: ok... maybe this will work for you then: `window.onload = function(){ setTimeout(function(){ Recaptcha.reload(); },1000); }`.

Comment: it does reload, but once the timeout is over is reverts back to the original image.

Comment: thank you for trying, i do appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: removed history API answer to show possible AJAX answer.

With jQuery it is ridiculously easy.

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#RecaptchaContainer').load('/path/to/recaptcha.php',function(){
         // any javascript you need to perform on the recaptcha
    });
});
```

You can have all the recaptcha HTML in that file, but you can contain all the javascript within that callback function.

Comment: The only issue i see with this is that all my users input on the form will be cleared, unless i am misunderstanding the events.  I know i can store the information, but i was hoping to keep things a little more contained.

Comment: alright then, use AJAX to load your recaptcha. It will be a different AJAX call and therefore should get pulled as new.

Comment: That sounds like it will work.  I havent worked with AJAX, so it may take me a little while to respond back with a confirmation.

Comment: i ended up finding a super simple hack that fixed the issue.  I added it to the end of my question as i cannot answer my own question for another 5 hours.  I appreciate your help though, i will upvote once i have enough cred to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easy method that works with Chrome:

Add reload function on HTML body as below:

```
<body onload="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">
```

And `reCaptcha` image auto reloads in Chrome when user click the back button.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to refresh correctly by using this line of code:

```
body onLoad="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"
```

But this method is not a good solution because the focus sets on the recaptacha text field, which means the window scrolls down to the bottom of the page which is where the recaptacha field is, even when you enter the page for the first time (not only when pressing "BACK" to the page).
This solution works but it would be better to find a solution which does not set the focus on the recaptacha input field.

Comment: Ok, solved! Many thanks to my friend Rubén Ayala. Te correct way is:
body onLoad="javascript:Recaptcha.reload('t')"
This makes it reload correctly but doesn't send the focus flying down to the bottom of the page.