# Refresh Destination Page when Back Button is Clicked using just Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with an image captcha.

If the user enters an incorrect code, an error page is displayed.

If they click "back" or the link I've provided that replicates the back button, they don't loose the form data, but the captcha doesn't change and even if they enter the correct image from this point, it won't work, so I want a new captcha to appear when they click back.

Refreshing the page creates a new captcha without loosing the form data, so I've been trying to refresh the destination page when the back button is clicked.

I've been attempting this by appending a parameter to the URL, so that I can check if ?captcha=back is included if so, refresh the page.

However, I've not been able to find any information on how to add a parameter when returning to a previous page, without the form data being lost.

The following kind of worked, but was just refreshing every page an extra time, which isn't what I wanted.

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
onload=function(){
var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
}
```

I was hoping something like below would work...

```
document.getElementById('captchaBack').addEventListener('click', function() {
    parent.history.back() + '?captcha=back';
    }, false);
```

I don't seem to be able to append anything to a back link.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The expiry date is confusing me slightly. Should I not worry about this too much and just delete the cookie once the page is refreshed?

Comment: I'm not using reCaptcha, but I've found the following link worked fine...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268467/reload-recaptcha-on-browser-back-button?rq=1
Thanks for trying to help with the cookie solutions anyway.